# How to write CPD for an academic?

Tags: professional-association, cpd

I was thinking that Continuing Professional Development (CPD) is for people who has routine job, and with CPD they renew their professional skills. Normally, by attending some courses, workshops, and practical programs. However, for an academic, we do this everyday through teaching and research.

I an assistant professor of applied physics mainly focused on research. In an application, I was asked to write about my CPD in one page. I have no idea what should I write. Aren't my teaching and research CPD? What should I write about my activities in academia in one page?

Any idea what should be the outlines of a CPD statement for an academic?

Comment: Who is asking you for this statement? What kind of application is it? I would think of listing conferences you've attended, and things like that.

Comment: In addition to @strongbad's mention of training courses for teaching, so much of your job involves (or will involve in the future) skills not taught in your academic learning. Have you been on any courses about managing people in your team? Have you been on courses to improve your public speaking? Have you been on courses about negotiation tactics? If you have an annual review of some sort, I'd suggest you discuss what CPD you could be doing.

Answer (score 3):

In general, CPD is for activities where you are being taught. So while we learn in while teaching and doing research, they generally do not qualify as CPD. In the UK, new faculty need to complete a Post Graduate Certificate in Higher Education (PGCHE). This is a taught course on teaching at the university level. A common form of CPD in my field are one day workshops on good clinical practice and courses on workshops on working with special populations (e.g., children and people with hearing loss). In addition to these practical CPD type things, conferences sometimes have special session CPD workshops which provide tutorial introduction to a field you may not normally stay on top of.

In Applied Physics I could imagine course/workshops either virtual or real on things like laser or radiation safety or proper use of large equipment (e.g., telescopes and particle accelerators). Obviously, they will depend on what you research is, but they might not be things you think of as CPD.